# Using Drupal 7 Rules, how to react to a file upload and change a node field?

Tags: nodes, rules, files

I have spent hours/days trying to figure out how to accomplish this in Drupal 7 using the Rules module, so I will greatly appreciate any help anyone can provide.

**What I am trying to do:**

When a user re-uploads a file to a node, the node should rollback from an Approved status to Pending Review. This requires some kind of automated rule that checks for when a file was updated.

**Here's what I have:**

1. A node called Data_set with a File field called data_set_file.
2. Data_set nodes also have a field called Status (e.g., Pending Review, Approved).

**My problem:**

When a user uploads and overwrites an existing attachment in the data_set_file field, I want the node's Status to change back from Approved (if already) to Pending Review. I am able to use Rules to check for when a user uploads a new file, but there are no rules conditions to check for which file or node file has been *updated*.

**What I tried:**

I created a "NOT Data Comparison" condition between **node-unchanged:field-dataset-file:file:fid** and (Equals/Negate) **node:field-dataset-file:file:fid** However, when updating the file, it did not register a change to the *fid* field (because it keeps the same fid). I also tried the file *size* field with no effect as well. When I tried the file's *timestamp*, it appeared to work at first until I realized that the timestamp updates *every time*, no matter what, that a user saves a node, regardless of whether or not a file was re-uploaded.

I may be going about this the wrong way. Anyone know what's the easiest way to accomplish this? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION.** After searching online, I found the answer to my own question. I'm sharing this for anyone else with a similar problem:

**The first part is to implement file events.** There is a patch to the Rules module that adds file events to react on (after saving new file, after updating existing file, and before saving file).

Discussion thread: https://www.drupal.org/node/826986

Patch: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/file_events-826986-22.patch

1. Copy the patch file to the rules module directory.
2. From the command line, change to ("cd") the rules module directory.
3. Enter: patch -p1 < file_events-826986-22.patch
4. On the Rules page (admin/config/workflow/rules) click "Add event" and
   select the file event to add.

**The next part is creating a rule to react to the file upload.**
A problem is that the timestamp on files are updated for every save, not just when it is first uploaded. So, I first opened my custom File Type (in my case "Dataset") and added a custom field using the Date Field Type called *Time Uploaded* (field_file_time_uploaded). I also created a new rule to update this field when the file is uploaded. Note that this rule gets called on the file insert event, which happens before a node is saved.

Below is what the rule export looks like for file uploads:

```
{ "rules_save_file_time_uploaded" : {
    "LABEL" : "File - Save Time Uploaded",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "file_insert" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_is_of_type" : { "entity" : [ "file" ], "type" : "file" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "file" ], "field" : "field_file_time_uploaded" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "file:field-file-time-uploaded" ],
          "value" : [ "site:current-date" ]
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "The [file:type] file was uploaded." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

This *Time Uploaded* field can then be used by other rules, like when saving a node, to see if the file was updated using a data comparison with the site's current datetime.

Answer (score 0):

[Workflow](https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow)

> This module allows you to create arbitrary Workflows, and assign them
>   to Entities.
>
> Workflows are made up of workflow states. Transitions between states
>   can be allowed per role. For example, a workflow with the states
>   Draft, Review, and Published could be assigned to the Story node type.
>   Only users with role 'chief editor' can set Stories to the published
>   state. You can set up the Workflow to alter states from form, page,
>   comment and a special workflow tab.
>
> Transitions between workflow states can have actions assigned to them.
>   In our example, we could assign an action so that when the story moves
>   from the Draft state to the Review state an email is sent out. Another
>   action could be assigned to the transition from Review to Published so
>   that the node's status is set to Published (and becomes visible on
>   your website).

**How we use workflow module**

[Creating a Workflow](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/workflow/)

[Editorial workflow with Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/550716)

Comment: read its documentation

Comment: On second thought, I don't think the answer above actually answered the original question. The workflow module still uses rules and I need to know how to implement a condition based on a file upload. Regardless of whether or not I use the workflow module, I still need to solve the problem of *how* do you react to a file upload? Is there a way? The documentation does not mention anything about that.